# How do I Uninstall SQL Server 2016 (64-bit) in Windows 10 Apps & Features

Tags: sql-server, windows

How do I Uninstall SQL Server 2016 (64-bit) in Windows 10 Apps & Features when Modify and Uninstall button is displayed but faded out and not accessible.

I have managed to uninstall all related SQL programs, but I am stuck with SQL Server 2016 (64-bit).

I have deleted the all Microsoft SQL servers folders in C:\Program Files and C:\Program Files (x86), I have deleted all SQL files related to SQL in the Registry. I have deleted all related SQL service files, but still SQL Server 2016 (64-bit) shows up in Apps & features. I assume there are some SQL files I did not have the guts to delete.

And I am not able to see any SQL files in Programs and Features.

From where does the SQL Server 2016 (64-bit) in Apps & features comes from? I like to delete SQL Server 2016 (64-bit) from Apps & features, before I do a new SQL installation.

Thanks,

Comment: > " have deleted the all Microsoft SQL servers folders in C:\Program Files and C:\Program Files (x86)" this is exactly how you **should not** uninstall programs. You've likely messed-up your system beyond repair now. You might have some success if you re-install SQL Server 2016 but at this point you should just reformat. This is an extreme course of action, but it's very easy to mess things up in a way that MSI / Windows Installer cannot repair and you end-up with headaches, especially for software as complicated (and with many shared components) as SQL Server.

Comment: You've broken the ability to properly uninstall by borking it all up trying to do it the wrong way. You're most likely fouled up beyond repair. The installer puts the information in the proper location for the Uninstall in Apps & Features  in order to allow you to uninstall properly. It's not there just to look pretty. Why didn't you use it in the first place?

Comment: Of course I did that in the first place, when the uninstall did not remove all the programs; then I started the manually removal. I have done this several times without problems. The only problem I have left is the program in Apps & features. If you know where the Apps & features pick up their programs; I have solved the issue.

Comment: @RBrattas Entries in the Add/Remove Programs list are stored in the `Uninstall` registry key, but SQL Server has multiple entries that correspond to different MSI packages which maintains the very complicated inter-dependency relationships between the packages - including the `Uninstall` key entries. Simply removing the `Uninstall` registry key entries for the SQL Server entries won't help because I guarantee that you have other components installed on your system (but no-longer properly registered, or vice-versa - both of which are huge issues).